# POST DATA issues when adding new elements to the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

Hi all I have a form in which I dynamically add in a new row consisting of a text box and check button on button press. However I need some sort of way to know which checkbuttons were pressed in the post data and therefore need a value field consisting of an ID on each of the the check buttons, code is seen below:

```
<div id='1'>
    <div class="template">
        <div>
            <label class="right inline">Response:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="responseText[]" value="" maxlength="400" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="responseRadio[]" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="addNewRow" value="Add Row" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS to add new row:

```
var $template = $('.template');
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    $template.clone().insertAfter($template);
});
```

can anyone suggest a good way to help me know in the post data which text field, links to which check button, and to know if it was pressed?

at the moment if you were to add 3 rows and check row 3 I have no way of identifying that row three was the button pressed - This is my issue

Comment: have u tried generating them dynamically?

Comment: ^ yeah how can this be acheived - I can't use a PHP variable as its server side and in JS its not as straightforward as value = "var counter" for example

Comment: ah.. No i was about to tell to use a php variable only

Answer (score 0):

after you cloned it, change the name so you know about this input

also it's good to have a counter for naming:

like : `'somename[myInput' + counter + ']'`

update:

```
var counter = 0;
var $template = $('.template');

$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    counter++;
    $template.clone().attr('name' , 'somename[myInput' + counter + ']').insertAfter($template);
});
```

now you have array named:*somename* which you can have a loop over its content on your form handler.

Comment: how would I do this and also how would I know when the users posts the data what to count up too?

Comment: thankyou I will give this a go and if I can get it working upvotes and right answer for you!